# Does it necessarily mean $A'\cap B'=$infinite, if $A\cap B=$infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This seems to be a silly question.

Suppose $A,~B,~A',~B'$ are all infinite sets such that $A' \subset A$ and $B' \subset B$.

$(1)$ Does it necessarily mean $A\cap B=$infinite, if $A'\cap B'=$infinite?

$(2)$ Does it necessarily mean $A'\cap B'=$infinite, if $A\cap B=$infinite?

The answer of question $(1)$ is trivial because $A' \cap B' \subset A \cap B$.

What about the question $(2)$ ?

It may happens that $A \setminus A'=$infinite and $B\setminus B'=$infinite such that $(A \setminus A') \cap (B \setminus B')=$infinite while $A' \cap B'$ might have only few elements in common, but still we have $A \cap B=$infinite.

So the answer of question $(2)$ is NO.

Am I correct ?

Thanks for discussion.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct to me. For question (2) you should probably try to construct an explicit example. You have the right idea, but you should really find such sets $A$, $B$, $A'$ and $B'$ to show that this idea can really happen.

Comment: That seems right. A simple example could be A,B are the integers, A' is the evens, B' is the odds. A and B interact over all integers, A' and B' have no common element.

Comment: @abnew123, thanks for pointing the example

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram.............